# UIButton is out of navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uistoryboard

I have a custom UI Button (just regular button but with image), within the navigation bar, but when I choose my image it looks like this in designer:

[image]

As you can see here, it's over my provider and status labels, and also when I run application it's over the WebView (which is bellow), so definitely out of navigation bar. I tried to find in storyboard some property where I can adjust this but I couldn't find any. I'm using swift and storyboards.

Appreciate any help, iOS newbie :)

Comment: would you add a screen shot of the application running on a device. I dont understand what is going on and what you are trying to change. Thanks 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure your 1x image is to the specified size (and then your 2x etc, or just use a PDF at the 1x size.

Icon sizes are here: [iOS Human Interface Guidelines: Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

I made my pdf 22x22 and added it to .xcassets with scale factor "single vector"

Comment: My bad, I made 60x60 for 1x image. I didn't realized that for navigation bar is different image size. So that's why button was "out" of navigation bar. I guess I will have to be more careful with these resolutions...

Comment: Recently did the exact same thing, hope you saved some time =)

Comment: Absolutely! You saved my day :)

Comment: However interesting thing is that they are not giving you exact size, they are saying "About" size... but I guess that's ok, and that it won't be very noticeable difference +- 1px :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description I think your issue is that you are trying to add a button for navigation. What you need is a `NavigationBar` with a `NavigationItem`/`BarButtonItem` in it. If you look in the object library you will be able to find these.

[image: Object Library]

Just drag them onto your story board. Once there select the button and in the side menu you will be able to select the Image for that Item. Now it is in the navigation bar up top. Let me know if there are still issues.

Comment: That's the first option that I tried, but for some reason image won't appear, button just got greyed and also out of navigation bar.

Comment: then the answer may be that your image is to big like @solenoid said. try making it smaller and see if that make it appear.

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue. I was using 60x60 for 1x.

Comment: yep i usually have 30X30 as my standard. Glad you figured it out.